# What is the correct mathematical notation for something comprised of the sum of constituents n where n is infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, infinity

I am trying to figure out what the correct mathematical notation would be for something like the following:

I want to describe that the value V of a company is equal to sum of parameters P at any given time t. The amount of parameters can in theory infinite. Understanding that it is impractical to determine an infinite amount of parameters, perhaps even impossible to describe all parameters I'm thinking about including a residual parameter to account for "unknowns".

What would be best way to describe such a relationship?

This is what I have come up with but I am unsure if this is mathematically bullet proof "proof-wise" and what the implications are of below formula.

$$
   V_{a_t} = \sum_{i=1}^nP_{i_t} + e; \lim_{n\to\infty} n = \infty 
$$

E.g. should $e$ be included or is better to just leave it out?
Hoping for some help as I am not an expert in the math field.

Comment: @avid19 - thanks for responding. I am not sure what this is let alone how to reach a correct notation based on this, sorry. Is it correct to $lim$ or should the notation be otherwise, like [i, ... n]

Comment: I misinterpreted. Your notation is okay but you need to add dependence on n for the error term.

Comment: Okay, something like $... + e_n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would write this is $$V(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} P_i (t)+\epsilon_n (t)$$

Where $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \epsilon_n (t)=0$ for all $t$

Comment: I see but with this notation does it say that $n$ is infinite also for $P_i$ and not only $ \epsilon_n (t)$?

Comment: You could just say there are infinitely many $P_i$. It would help if there was more context.

Comment: $V(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n\to\infty} P_i (t)+\epsilon_n (t)$ - would this be correct with $^{n\to\infty}$? 
One of the things I want to arrive at with the formula is to be able to state: to minimize residual effects requires increasing the number of $P$'s. In order to reach zero residual effects, $n$ must be infinity I guess.

Comment: Have you seen Taylor series before? There's a similar statement about the remainder term. Look up Taylor's remainder theorem.

Comment: Okay I will try to look this up and try understanding it too :) Math is a distant cousin to me.

Comment: Don't spend too much time on that. It's just something that's in a similar spirit.

Comment: Okay thank you very much - my final question: is this notation correct: $V(t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n\to\infty}...$ having $n\to\infty$ above $\sum$?

Comment: That is not convention. You would just have an $\infty$ in the top.

Answer (score 0):

You can readily write
$V(t)=\sum_{i\in I} P_i(t)$ where $I$ is an index set (which may be infinite). However, in the infinite case we do not really have a sum with all its nice properties any more (unless all but finitel many summands are zero):

- The sum may not be defined (converge) if "too many" of the $P_i(t)$ are "too large"
- Especially, if $I$ is uncountable and uncountably many $P_i(t)$ are nonzero, we are in serious trouble
- If the $P_i(t)$ have different signs then without a natural or implied order on $I$ the "sum" is not defined (i.e., different orders may result in differnt sums)

Comment: About the sum - the limit of the sum is basically whatever any investor can afford to pay for the company. In theory that could be anywhere between negative infinite amount dollars to positive. For the negative, it would be imply that the investor is requried to get a sum of money in order for him him to buy the company. In practical terms negatives are not common, also infinite very impractical.